# how to change default directory of output files of sass-autocompile in atom

Tags: sass

using *sass-autocompile* in atom it works fine, but I need to change output files(file.min.css). minified files saved to current directory. how can I set for target directory as 'currentPath/minifiedFiles' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setting of the package. But this setting will be applied globally.

Goto "Filename pattern for 'compressed' compiled files" you can change the settings there

Say this is the directory structure

```
\---app
    +---css
    |       main.scss
    |       
    \---dist
            main.min.css
```

In the file name pattern you can give  `../dist/$1.min.css` This will compile main.scss and export to 'dist' directory automatically.